# Why does my Lightbox gallery load imgs in separate page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am learning web design and am quite new to it. So please excuse any ignorant questions. I struggled to create a img that would work with both my MagnificPopUp light-box gallery and my custom css img hover effects. After doing so, when clicking on a img it no longer creates a light-box gallery but instead loads the image in a separate page. I can't understand why it's doing this, I have tried many different classes, such as "image-link" but it does the same thing.

Heres my Document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prociono" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">

        <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js">

        <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/magnific-popup.css"> 

        <!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
        <script src="./dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>



    </head>


    <body>
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <section id="header">

            <h1 class="name">Jessica Shae</h1>


            <div class="container heading">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 animated rotateInDownLeft">
                        <img src="img/7.jpg" class="display">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" class="display">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 animated rotateInDownRight">
                        <img src="img/9.jpg" class="display">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-xs-center">
                            <a href="#gallery"<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 

                </div>
            </div>


        </section>

        <!-- Gallery -->

        <section id="gallery">

            <h2 class="title">The Dark Room</h2>

            <div class="container photo-collection wow animated fadeInUpBig">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <a class="gallery-item" href="img/3.jpg" title="Title"><img src="img/3.jpg" class="work"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/10.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/4.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/18.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/6.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/17.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/5.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/11.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/14.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/20.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/13.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/16.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/15.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/12.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>




        </section>




        <section class="contact-me">
            <div class="contact">
                <h3><span class="white">Conta</span><span class="black">ct Me</span></h3>
            </div>


            <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
                    </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
                    </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label>Drop me a line:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                    </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
                    </div>     
                </div>



                </div>
            </form>
        </section>

    <section class="copywrite">
        <h6>Copywrite &copy; 2016 built by Temple Cerulean Naylor</h6>
    </section>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.gallery-item').magnificPopup({
                type: 'image'});

        });
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please use jsfiddle or codepen to show us whatever you have done so far.

Comment: go to http://codepen.io/pen/ and paste your code.i know you are a beginner so don't forget to save the pen and post the link here so that we can see your working design.

Comment: This is the link http://codepen.io/templenaylor/pen/eBNvyX

Comment: But the page doesn't display like it does within my browser. The whole background is white instead of black. If you just need it to see my complete code, then there you go, but if not, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js">` this is not css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a tag before image for Magnific popup box gallery
some of tag hasn't have closing tag and wrongly linked js file

PC : [http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Multi-Functional-jQuery-Lightbox-Plugin-Magnific-Popup/

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
     delegate: 'a',
     type: 'image',
     tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
     mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
     gallery: {
       enabled: true,
       navigateByImgClick: true,
       preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
     },
     image: {
       tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
       titleSrc: function(item) {
         return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
body {
  /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
  background: #070606;
}
/* HEADER */

.display {
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 6%;
}
.heading {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.name {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
h1:after {
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #e62222;
  /*Great way to give single line color */
  content: " ";
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.fa {
  margin-top: 18px;
}
.fa:link,
/*Prevents color change when clicked */

.fa:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
.fa:hover,
.fa:active {
  color: #ebedee;
}
/* GALLERY */

.work {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'Prociono', serif;
  font-size: 350%;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.affect img {
  opacity: 0.2;
  background-color: #070606;
  transition: opacity .35s, transform .35s;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
.affect:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
/* CONTACT */

.contact-me {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.white {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 240%;
}
.black {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 240%;
}
.contact-form {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e62222;
}
textarea {
  height: 100px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #e62222;
  border: 1px solid #e62222;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: #e94141;
}
/* *:focus {outline: none;} */

/* ------Copywrite----- */

.copywrite {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.copywrite h6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.contact-me label {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  color: white;
}
/* -----ANIMATIONS-----*/

.wow {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Multi-Functional-jQuery-Lightbox-Plugin-Magnific-Popup/dist/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Multi-Functional-jQuery-Lightbox-Plugin-Magnific-Popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prociono" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<section id="header">

  <h1 class="name">Jessica Shae</h1>


  <div class="container heading">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 animated rotateInDownLeft">
        <img src="http://www.life.org.uk/dump/media/animal-adaptation-animal-adaptation-800-360.jpg" class="display">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-028.jpg" class="display">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 animated rotateInDownRight">
        <img src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-021.jpg" class="display">
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-xs-center">
          <a href="#gallery"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<!-- Gallery -->

<section>

  <h2 class="title">The Dark Room</h2>

  <div class="popup-gallery">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-021.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-021.jpg" class="work" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-020.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-020.jpg" class="work" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-019.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-019.jpg" class="work" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-018.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-018.jpg" class="work" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-016.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-016.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-017.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-017.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-015.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-015.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-011.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-011.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-014.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-014.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-012.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-012.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-013.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-013.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-016.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-016.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-011.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-011.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-015.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-015.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 affect">
        <a class="aitem" href="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-012.jpg" title="Title">
          <img width="75" height="75" src="https://a2ua.com/animal/animal-012.jpg" class="work">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>




</section>




<section class="contact-me">
  <div class="contact">
    <h3><span class="white">Conta</span><span class="black">ct Me</span></h3>
  </div>


  <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-2-of-3">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-2-of-3">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <label>Drop me a line:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-2-of-3">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-2-of-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
      </div>
    </div>


  </form>
</section>

<section class="copywrite">
  <h6>Copywrite &copy; 2016 built by Temple Cerulean Naylor</h6>
</section>
```

Comment: I really appreciate all time time you took to help me out, but sadly this doesn't create the lightbox effect and still loads the picture in a separate page for me. I will definitely mark you as the answer though since you took all that time to help me. Thank you.

Comment: @younCoder have you tried to match call with mine. i think you have used unnecessary js file in your code. Remove some and try again will work